# A problem regarding complex variable equation $sz+t\bar{z}+r=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Let $s,t,r$ be non-zero complex numbers and $L$ be the set of solutions $z=x+iy$ $(x,y \in \mathbb{R}, i^2=-1)$ of the equation 
$$sz+t\bar{z}+r=0$$

where $\bar{z}=x-iy$.Then, which of the following statement(s) is (are) TRUE?

$$\begin{aligned}
\text{(A)}&  \textrm{ If }L \textrm{ has exactly one element, then }|s|\neq |t|\\
\text{(B)}&  \textrm{ If }|s|=|t|,\textrm{ then }L\textrm{ has infinitely many elements}\\
\text{(C)}&  \textrm{ The number of elements in }L \cap \lbrace z:|z-1+i|=5\rbrace\textrm{ is at most } 2\\
\text{(D)}&  \textrm{ If }L\textrm{ has more than one element, then }L\textrm{ has infinitely many elements }\dots
\end{aligned}$$

Can anyone please give me some clue to proceed?

Comment: the (C) option is not well stated plese clarify.

Comment: This is not clear to me as well...@Dr Zafar Ahmed DSc

Comment: I will surely get back to you.

Answer (score 2):

**Options (A), (C), (D) are correct:**

The relation $$s\bar z+t z+r=0~~~(1) \implies \bar s z + t \bar z +\bar r=0~~~~(2)$$ where $s,t,r$ are complex numbers, being a linear (first degree in $z$) can at best represent a line in Argand plane otherwise a point or nothing (null set).

Eliminating $z$ like in previous Answer, we have
$$(|s|^2-|t|^2)z=\bar r t - r \bar s $$
(A) So when $(|s|^2-|t|^2)\ne 0$, then there is a unique solution: $z=\frac{\bar r t - r \bar s} {(|s|^2-|t|^2)}.$

(B) When $(|s|^2-|t|^2)= 0$, then $\bar r t - r\bar s$ may or may not be zero, so there may be no solution or many solution. In this regard (B) is not essentially true.

(C) The given new locus is a circle and $L$ contains no point, one point or more than one points (line). As a line can cut the circle in at most two points the option (C) is correct.

(D) If $L$ has more than one point it will have infinitely many point as (1) would represent a line

Answer (score 0):

Note

$$sz+t\bar{z}=-r, \>\>\>\>\> \bar s \bar z+\bar t {z}=-\bar r$$

Eliminate $\bar z$ to get

$$(|s|^2 -|t^2|)z = \bar rt-r\bar s$$

Note that, if $|s|^2 \ne |t^2|$, a unique solution $z = \frac{\bar rt-r\bar s}{|s|^2 -|t^2|}$ exists.

On the other hand, if $|s|^2 =|t^2|$, no solutions exist in general. Yet, in the special case where $|s|^2 =|t^2|$ and $\bar rt=r\bar s$, any $z$ satisfies the equation.

Thus, (A) and (D) are true.

Comment: Can you please little bit elaborate why there will be unique solution when not equal to and no solution when denominator and numerator are both zero?@quanto

Comment: Can you please tell me why the option (c) is not true?

Comment: @sani - when $\ne$, the solution for $z$ is explicitly given in the answer. When $=$ and $\bar r t - r\bar s \ne  0$, there is no solution; when = and $\bar r t - r\bar s = 0$, there are infinite solutions (any $z$ satisfies the equation).

Comment: @sani - For (C), note that $|z-1+i|=5$ represents a circle, i.e. infinite number of solutions.

Comment: Can you please read the option  $C$ once again?@Quanto

Comment: @sani - (C) is not true, because in the case of infinite solutions for $z$, $\textrm{ The number of elements in }L \cap \lbrace z:|z-1+i|=5\rbrace\textrm{ is more than } 2$

Comment: Why more than 2? Can you please tell me little more on this?@Quanto

Comment: $L$ can be an empty set. @Quanto

Comment: @sani - Note that the elements in $\{z:|z-1+i|=5\}$ are infinite, which are also the elements in L in the case of $|s|^2 =|t^2|$ and $\bar rt=r\bar s$, hence more than 2.

Comment: Yea I got you why $C$ is not true..But I think I need more explanation for the cases of infinite and unique solution is needed.@Quanto

Comment: @Sani - Agree you need examine and understand all three cases, i.e. unique, no solution and infinite solutions. It turns out the infinite case disqualifies (C).

Comment: @Sani you may like my solution posted just now.