# If a complex number has infinitely many solutions why is it a line?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Let $s,t,r$ be non-zero complex numbers and $L$ be the set of solutions $z = x+iy \text{ },\:x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ of the equation $sz+t\bar{z}+r=0$ where $\bar{z} = x-iy$.

Prove the number of elements in $L \cap \{z: |z-1+i|=5\}$ is at most $2$.

---

What they did in the solution is say $z(|s|^2-|t|^2) = \bar{r}t-r\bar{s}$. They did this by taking conjugate of the original equation and eliminating $\bar{z}.$

Now how is $L \cap \{z: |z-1+i|=5\}$ is at most $2$?

If $|s| \neq |t|$, $z = \dfrac{\bar{r}t-r\bar{s}}{(|s|^2-|t|^2)}$ which is one solution and it can intersect the circle once. If $|s| = |t|$ and  $\bar{r}t-r\bar{s}\neq0$ then $L$ is empty. But if $|s| = |t|$ and  $\bar{r}t-r\bar{s}=0$, then $z\cdot0=0 \implies$ $z$ has infinitely many solutions. Why is $L$ a line in this case? Isn't it the entire plane? Why does it intersect the circle at most twice?

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3552557/a-problem-regarding-complex-variable-equation-szt-barzr-0) Z Ahmed told its a line but I can't seem to wrap my head around why this is the case.

Comment: Your equation $z ( |s|^2 - |t|^2) = \bar r t - r \bar s$ is completely different than the equation $s z + t \bar z + r = 0$ in the linked question.

Comment: ok lemme change that

Comment: @BrianMoehring i copied the qstn wrong sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brian seems to have given a complete solution, but to address your specific confusion: You're right that the equation $$z(|s|^2-|t|^2) = \bar{r}t - r\bar{s}$$ will have infinitely many solutions if $|s|^2 - |t|^2 = 0$ and $\bar{r}t - r\bar{s}= 0.$  But, in that case, the elimination method step (where we solve for $z$ by eliminating the conjugate) is producing the trivial equation $0 = 0,$ which loses the original solution set.  The arbitrary $z$ values you choose won't satisfy the original equation - only this secondary equation.

For example, take $s = t = \frac{1}{2}$ and $r = -1$ so that the original equation becomes $$\frac{z}{2} + \frac{\bar{z}}{2} - 1 = 0,$$ which is equivalent to $\Re(z) = 1$.  Clearly that solution set is a line.

If you take the conjugate equation and use it to eliminate $\bar{z}$, then $z$ will be eliminated as well, and you'll get the equation $0z + 0\bar{z} = 0$, which does have infinitely many solutions but isn't equivalent to the original equation.  We've lost the original equation's information.

The overall problem is arising because the conjugate equation is a multiple of the original equation in this degenerate case, so it's not useful for elimination.  For example, if you start with the system of equations \begin{array}{11}x + y = 0\\2x + 2y = 0,\end{array} then there's a line (not plane) of solutions: $\{(x, -x): x \in \mathbb{R}\}$, but the elimination method will kill both variables and lose this information, because this is a dependent system of equations.  You've identified the conditions under which the conjugate trick/elimination method fails.

Comment: It is a little unfortunate that the answer given under Z Ahmed's in your link seems to have fallen for the same trap.  They're right that the final equation is satisfied by any $z$, but they miss that we've lost the original solution set by then.

Comment: Yep that sucks. But I don't understand how he realised it's a line despite making this mistake. Must've just tried matching the answer key and wrote that.

Comment: I don't think Z Ahmed made any mistakes there, but I think it's an incomplete answer - the elimination method is still useful for proving parts a. and b., even if it doesn't completely solve parts c. and d.  But the other answer makes it seem like the degenerate elimination step implies that the original solution set is the full plane, while I think Z Ahmed knew it was a line (being a non-trivial linear relationship between $x$ and $y$).  I think Z just didn't mention/show that part.

Answer (score 1):

The equation $sz + t\bar{z} + r = 0$ can be rewritten in terms of $x,y$ as
$$s(x+iy) + t(x-iy) + r = 0 \\ (s+t)x + i(s-t)y + r = 0$$

- If $s-t \neq 0$, we may solve for $y$ as $$y = \frac{i(s+t)}{s-t}x + \frac{ir}{s-t}$$
  which describes either a line, a point, or an empty set.
- If $s-t = 0$, then the equation becomes $$2sx + r = 0 \\ x = -\frac{r}{2s}$$
  which describes either a line or an empty set.

---

Alternatively, if you're having trouble seeing how these are the solution sets, it may be easier to just go back to $$(s+t)x + i(s-t)y + r = 0 \\ \iff \\ \begin{cases}\Re(s+t) x + \Im(t-s)y + \Re(r) = 0 \\ \Im(s+t)x + \Re(s-t)y + \Im(r) = 0\end{cases}$$
so the solution set is the intersection of two real linear equations, each of which is either empty, a line, or the whole plane.  The intersection of two such sets is either empty, a point, a line, or the whole plane, and we may ignore the whole plane as a possibility since, e.g., $r\neq 0$.

Comment: why have you written $sz-t\bar{z}+r=0$ in first line? Question is $sz+t\bar{z}+r=0$

Comment: @Sid It was just a typo.  I've fixed it.  Any other concerns?

Comment: Could you explain how $ x = \frac{-r}{2s}$ could represent an empty set? also in the last two linear equation, I understood how you get the real part equation and imaginary part equation biut how did you conclude two l inear equations can be solution set look like a line? If you have two lines then they will intersect a point or not, no?

Comment: @Buraian Taking imaginary parts, $x = -\frac{r}{2s}$ becomes $0 = \Im\left(-\frac{r}{2s}\right)$ which means it describes an empty set when $r/s$ is non-real.  For your second question, you have two ways for the solution set to be a line: (1) One of the real linear equations is $0=0$ (the whole plane) and the other is any line, so the intersection is the line or (2) Both real linear equations describe the same line, and intersecting a line with itself still gives the line.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Isn't it possbile that set $L$ wil have two different lines as solution. These two lines will give four solution with given circle.

Comment: @mathophile No.  I'm just guessing on how you find the union of two lines, but when we say a complex number $w=0$, it means both the real and complex parts of $w$ are zero, not one or the other.  This means the two real linear equations I found (if that is the two lines you're talking about) must be simultaneously satisfied, giving the intersection, not the union, of two lines.

Answer (score 0):

Your equation is never true on the entire plane (as you've stated the hypothesis that the coefficients $s,t,r$ are nonzero), otherwise, you've defined the function $f(z) = z^{*}$ (* denotes conjugate) as a linear function $z$, which is absurd, not least because $z^{*}$ isn't holomorphic.

You've incorrectly stated -- given a simultaneous system, the equation yielded by subtracting one equation from another provides a complete description of the solution set, but clearly it just gives a new constraint. (well, to be exact not new, just incomplete) Therefore, in the case $|s|=|t|$, you found this new constraint tells you nothing new at all, which just means you have to go back to the original system and solve it some other way.

Perhaps the easiest way to see the solution is a point or a line is to expand the equation into its real and imaginary parts, i.e. you get two linear equations in $x$,$y$. Their solutions are lines. It turns out when $|s|=|t|$, those two lines coincide, and when $|s|\neq |t|$, they do not, therefore those two lines are parallel or intersect at a point. In fact, you've shown they must intersect at a point. To see why $|s|=|t|$ is the right condition for those two lines to coincide, consider a geometric description of a line in the Argand diagram.